# Disable git in Aptana? Or make git more compatible over samba?

Tags: git, aptana, samba

I'm using Aptana from a Windows client to make changes to the working directory of a Git repo stored on a Debian machine.  I'm using Samba to share the working directory (and Git repo).

Unfortunately when I'm working in Aptana, every file I have is marked as change (from the perspective of the last commit). When I do a commit from within Aptana, all the asterisks go away, but then when I run `git log` on the server, the asterisks come back.

Is there a way to fix this situation?  Is there a way to disable Git support in aptana all together?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because Windows doesn't support UNIX file modes. Samba provides this information, but Windows doesn't use it.

The mode that's stored in the index file is different from the mode that Git on Windows is reporting the file to actually have. This happens because there aren't any real UNIX style file modes on Windows, so they're just made up on the fly. When you run "git log" on the server, it rewrites the index file to have the correct (Unix) file modes again.

Comment: It's weird, it kind of lists all the files, but doesn't show any differences to them so it's just blank.

Comment: that makes sense - the mode that's stored in the index file is different from the mode that Git on Windows is reporting the file to actually have. This happens because there aren't any real UNIX style file modes on Windows, so they're just made up on the fly. When you run "git log" on the server, it rewrites the index to use the actual file modes again.